# Determine if item is a list item or document

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

How can I determine if a fetched item is a list item or a document/file? I thought about using SPFileSystemObjectType but list items come back as files.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

actually an item always is an item (`SPListItem` object).
If you fetch an item from a library, you have to use `SPItem.File` to get the appropriate `SPFile` object.

To ensure, you have a file, you can use the `Exists` property of `SPFile` (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.exists.aspx).

```
...
var item = GetListItemById(1);
if (item.File.Exists)
{
     var file = item.File;
     //handle file
}
...
```

HTH,
Daniel